# How to sign in into Angular an app with Windows login using Singel Sign On

Tags: angular, windows, single-sign-on

I am working on an Angular application and I need to implement SSO so that when I login into my Windows computer with username and password, my Angular app should use these Windows credentials to log me in into the app.

Is there anyone who could help me with ideas on how to implement Single-Sign-On (Windows and Angular 8 app)? I will appreciate if you can share code examples or any material that could be of help.

Cheers

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: Well nothing so to say, I have just done the AuthGuard and Interceptor of a thing. I don't really have idea on what is applicable. That was why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a node package like [passport-windowsauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-windowsauth) and [passport-ldapauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth) to provide windows based authentication

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Just install msal-angular plugin or adal-angular plugin. I used adal-angular.

Then add the below code in app.module.ts

```
MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({
        tenant: 'your-tenant-id',
        clientId: 'your-client-id',
        redirectUri: "a-url",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
        cacheLocation: '<localStorage / sessionStorage>'
      })
```

Then add the below line in login page.

```
this.adalService.login();
```